# How to display validation errors in CakePHP 3.6?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-3.x

I'm having trouble displaying the validation errors of a form using a custom validator.
The errors does exist as the debug method shows, it just won't be displayed in the form.

I'd like to be able to show the error message under (or above, or anywhere) the field.

## What I've tried

Well, the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#displaying-errors) does state:

> When using View\Helper\FormHelper::control(), errors are rendered by
>   default, so you don’t need to use isFieldError() or call error()
>   manually.

Nevertheless, I added the following in the form (just below the email control), which didn't do anything more. No message displayed.

```
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('email')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('email', 'Yes, it fails!');
}
```

I've also found several questions and answers about this issue on SO, but they look outdated (from '09 to '13) and do not seem to correspond to today's CakePHP syntax.

## What I've done

**Users/forgot_password.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email', ['type' => 'email']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Reset my password')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**UsersController.php**

(notice the specific validation set, as explained in [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set))

```
public function forgotPassword()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->getData(), ['validate' => 'email']);
        if ($user->errors()) {
            debug($user->errors()); // <- shows the validation error
            $this->Flash->error(__('An error occurred.'));
        } else {

          // ... procedure to reset password (which works fine!) and redirect to login...

          return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
    }
}
```

**UsersTable.php**

```
public function validationEmail(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->notEmpty('email', __('An email address is required.'));

    return $validator;
}
```

## What it looks like

[image]

## Update

Thanks to @ndm comment, here is the correct way to display the error.

In **UsersController.php**:

```
public function forgotPassword()
{
    // user context for the form
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity(§user, $this->request->getData(), ['validate' => 'email']); <- validation done on patchEntity
        if ($user->errors()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('An error occurred.'));
        } else {

          // ... procedure to reset password and redirect to login...

          return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
    }

    // pass context to view
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

And in the view **forgotPassword.ctp**:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
```

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447781/cakephp-3-5-validation-error-mesages-not-showing-on-fields**

Comment: @ndm Thank you! I haven't seen this answer which fixes my problem. I was indeed missing the context. It's all clear now.

Answer (score -2):

```
//modify your function as below 
public function forgotPassword()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->getData(), ['validate' => 'email']);
    if ($user->getErrors()) {
        debug($user->getError('email')); // <- shows the validation error
        $this->Flash->error(__($user->getError('email')['_empty']));
    } else {

      // ... procedure to reset password (which works fine!) and redirect to login...

      return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a good idea, from having to adjust the controller everytime rules are being changed, to machines not being able read form errors. There's no reason for the controller to be involved with this, the form helper can handle errors just fine when fed with the correct data.

Comment: This does not really answer my question on how to display the message under (or next) to the field which failed validation. In a UX perspective I believe it is better to show validation errors next to the fields that failed rather than in a flash message.
And as @ndm mentioned, this is a poor practice as you'd need to update your controller method every time your rules or form change.